# .net datagridview cell minimum width

Tags: .net, datagridview, managed-c++

I have a `datagridview`. I set `AutoSizeColumnsMode` property to `Fill`. However I want to set a minimum width for the columns. So, when too many columns are created, the scroll bar is shown.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the DataGridViewColumn.MinimumWidth property to do it:

```
DataGridViewColumn^ column = dataGridView->Columns[ 1 ];
column->MinimumWidth = 40;
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.minimumwidth.aspx)